# Unisex word (or short phrase) for "little black book"

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, synonyms

Although it seems like this phrase is already unisex, something about it gives it a feminine tone. I'm looking for a phrase that means "a list a lovers" but can be used by both men and women in contemporary language, leaning towards slang. Any ideas?

Comment: I haven't heard the phrase "little black book" in decades, but back when it was more common, it was more typically men who were supposed to carry one, not women.

Comment: I'm coining the term *Lust List* (although I bet if I googled it, it would already exist)

Comment: Perhaps you are thinking of the term '*little black dress*' when assigning it femininity. *Little Black Book* used to be a term for a list of lovers that men kept (it was usually like a small black diary - A7 roughly)

Comment: What??  Isn't this just your Facebook friends list??

Comment: @Smock Lust List sounds cool, but a bit vulgar IMO. And Little Black Book would be perfect for what I am looking for but it is a bit overused. I guess I am looking to build a new phrase that uses more everyday slang (U.S.).

Answer (score 2):

Where back in the 1970's somebody would call someone out of their little black book to arrange casual sex, nowadays you make a *booty call* to one of your your *friends with benefits* for a *hook-up*.

But in the post-AIDS era, it's unlikely somebody has so many f.w.b.'s that they need to keep a special list of them. And they probably keep their numbers on their smart phone along with all their other contacts, rather than in a paper booklet.

Comment: In a British workplace context, if your manager or supervisor has 'put you in his (or her) little black book', that means that some (bad) aspect of your conduct or performance has been noted, and you are being watched.

Comment: In the first paragraph, you give great suggestions, but I need them to be a bit less vulgar. To reduce vulgarity, instead of making them sex themed I'd rather them be love themed, but I don't know what fun and edgy words to use to describe temporary love...